# is apache camel clusterable when using the file component?

Tags: file, cluster-computing, apache-camel

Is it possible to use apache camel is a cluster when using the file compoment?
For example the following rout:

```
from("file://C:/temp/camel/in?moveFailed=/temp/camel/error&delay=10000&delete=true")
     .to("file://C:/temp/camel/out")
```

Will camel know it file has already been taken by one member of the cluster? 
What if both camel instances take the file at the same time?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes read the docs about the read lock option, where you have different options to setup this.